# Insert logging into existing binary code, ARM

Tags: c++, arm, patching

I want to add logging to some function(s) in the shared (`.so`) library. (ARM, Android, a mix of Arm and Thumb modes; C++, some functions are virtual and therefore nameless, invoked via VFT.)

***Does anyone already have code that does this or almost this? (Adds logging to existing functions.)***

(I am thinking about patching at run-time (on-the-fly), but you may suggest something static.)

The procedures usually start with a `PUSH`/`STM` instruction, but it's difficult to place a branch into just one instruction, at least in the thumb mode.
***How do I modify existing procedures?***

One more issue is to detect code residing in PLT.
***How do I detect code in PLT, how do I "dereference" the plt entry?***

Related info:

The caching issues are discussed here:
[Patching ARM7 code during runtime](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/patching-arm7-code-during-runtime) (but no code at the moment).

Qt-specific stuff: http://www.ntcore.com/files/qtrev.htm or (the same) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31330/Qt-Internals-Reversing and [about Qt signals&slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

About [printing out RTTI](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4329/4398) (when it's available, of course).

UPD: [**reDroid**: reverse-engineering tools for Android NDK/C++/Qt (source at github)](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid).

Answer (score 4):

[The Android Dynamic Binary Instrumentation Toolkit (adbi)](https://github.com/crmulliner/adbi) should allow you to do what you need to do.

> Simple binary instrumentation toolkit for Android ARM + Thumb.
>
> Instrumentation is based on library injection and hooking function
>   entry points (in-line hooking).
>
> The toolkit consists of two main components the hijack tool and the
>   base library.
>
> **hijack**
>
> The hijack tool provides the injection functionality. It supports a
>   number of modes for supporting older and newer Android devices. hijack
>   provides help on the command line.
>
> **libbase**
>
> The base library provides the hooking and unhooking functionality. The
>   base library is compiled as a static library so it can be directly
>   included in the actual instrumentation library. This is done so we can
>   keep everything in /data/local/tmp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dynamic Binary Instrumentation to achieve what you want as suggested by [Jason Geffner](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1562/jason-geffner).

You can use [PINdroid](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/256671/pindroid-tutorial.pdf) by Intel. Read this presentation on [Android Binary Instrumentation](http://www.mulliner.org/android/feed/binaryinstrumentationandroid_mulliner_summercon12.pdf).

Comment: As to Pin, is there ARM support? _Pin is used for the instrumentation of programs. It supports Linux*,Windows*, macOS and 
Android* executables for IA-32, and Intel(R) 64._

Comment: If I'm not wrong then yes, you can use Pindroid for ARM too. I have not used it in Android. But according to me, yes you can. [Pindroid Tutorial](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/256671/pindroid-tutorial-01_1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

What i usually do, is find a suitable BL or BLX  instruction, and replace it with a BL to my logging code,  at the end of my logginghook, then jump to the original target.

original code:

```
MOV R0, #123
BLX  somefunction
```

then in `C` i write some function:

```
int hooksomefunction(int arg)
{
     // insert logging code here

     return somefunction(arg);
}
```

and change the original code to:

```
MOV R0, #123
BLX  hooksomefunction
```

Other methods of inserting a call of your own:

- insert your code over some error handling code, which is unlikely to be actually used.
- write a jump over some instructions, copy those instructions to the start of your hook, call your logging code, jump back.